# Recursive function with templates results in recursive instantiation (clang)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang

I have the following code and I dont understand Why this compiles with clang 3.5

```
   /** Greates common divisor */
   template<bool argsPositive = false,
            typename T
            >
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,T >::type
    gcd2( T  a, T  b )
    {

        if(!argsPositive){
            a = std::abs( a );
            b = std::abs( b );
        }

        if( a == 0  ||  a == b ){
            return  b;
        }
        if( b == 0 ){
            return  a;
        }
        if( a > b ){
            return  gcd2<true,T>( a % b, b );
        }
        else{
            return  gcd2<true,T>( a, b % a );
        }
    }
```

and this code where the enable_if is inside the template parameter declaration results in an recursive instantiation loop where the compiler crashes:

```
   /** Greates common divisor */
   template<bool argsPositive = false,
            typename T,
            typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type * = nullptr
            >
    T gcd2( T  a, T  b )
    {
     ....
    }
```

Is that a compiler bug, GCC does compile fine:  [LINK](http://ideone.com/g81Ju9)

Comment: Compiles [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e1d43f86f362b46)

Comment: What version of clang are you using?

Comment: clang 3.5 (in text above)

Comment: Both versions seems perfectly fine. Please file a bug report at http://llvm.org/bugs and attach the files provided by clang. It's never ok when a compiler crashes.